# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException in google search

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Can not enter into google search page as getting exception of `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException` in Google search

using the code below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.List;

public class GoogleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sb_ifc0']")).sendKeys("selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sblsbb']/button")).click();
        List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(allLinks.size());

        for(int i=0;i<allLinks.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(allLinks.get(i).getText()+"----"+allLinks.get(i).isDisplayed());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are the 3 problems:

**1**) The selector for search box is a div element and not a proper textbox or input tag hence the exception `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException`

as you wish to enter a text hence use the following selector

```
//*[@id = 'sb_ifc0']//input[@id = 'lst-ib']
```

**2**) The other thing is you are not using any waits, an implicit wait can save you the day here.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**3**) As you are getting the list of elements by anchor tag before looping through them the reference to the list items is going stale hence you may refresh the element reference by getting a new reference every time in the loop.

```
  for(int i=0; i<allLinks.size(); i++)
  {
       List<WebElement> allLink = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
       System.out.println(allLink.get(i).getText()+"----"+allLink.get(i).isDisplayed());
  }
```

The following the working version of the code problem code:

```
    /**
     * Created by anirudh on 18/4/15.
     */
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public class GoogleTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id = 'sb_ifc0']//input[@id = 'lst-ib']")).sendKeys("selenium");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id = 'sblsbb']/button")).click();
            List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            System.out.println(allLinks.size());

            for(int i = 0; i<allLinks.size(); i++)
            {
                List<WebElement> allLink = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                System.out.println(allLink.get(i).getText()+"----"+allLink.get(i).isDisplayed());
            }
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the proper link, in the driver.get()

```
 driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just try below code for searching in google

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.List;

public class Googlesearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sblsbb']/button")).click();
       List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(elements.size());
    }
}
```